# How to properly maintain a listening port for a long time?

Tags: c, sockets, daemon

I wrote this small server application in pure C that listens to incoming connections in a given port, very simple stuff.

It goes with the usual socket initialization procedure, create the `socket()` then `bind()` to the port, says its a `listen()`, and ifinitely loops through a `select()` waiting for incoming connections to `accept()`.

All goes just fine and works like a charm, except that if I leave the thing running for a couple months, the listening port closes while the application server keeps running unaware of it, since I wrote it to trust the listening socket will not close if not told to.

So the question is: Why the hell is the port being closed without my application's concern and what can I do to prevent it from happening?

Is that expected behaviour? Should I check for some kind of exceptions or make "health check" on the listening socket to reopen it if necessary?

Code: https://gist.github.com/Havenard/e930be035a3bee75c018 (yes I realize I'm using `0` as cue for errors and it's bad pratice and stuff, but it is not relevant to the question as I explained in the comments, when I set the socket file descriptor to `0` it is to stop the loop and shut down the application).

Comment: It's not normal.  I would suspect some sort of resource leak in your application, such as running out of file descriptors because you don't close the new socket returned by accept().

Comment: The descriptors closes are being handled, and the service is rarely used. Normally it don't get new connections for weeks. Besides, its not an accept() problem. The port really closes, it disasppears from the netstat list and other applications can bind to that port as if nothing was using it.

Comment: Select() would result in an invalid filedescriptor being reported/error'd. Maybe you closed it by dup2()ing over it ?

Comment: In my code if select() return < 0 the program terminates, which is not happening. select() gives me the option to specify a FD_SET for exceptions, but I'm not using it because nobody seems to use it and theres nearly zero documentation on how to handle this thing properly. I basically do `if (select(maxfd, &fdsets, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0) break;` and then if `FD_ISSET(skt_bind, &fdsets)` I just try to accept the connection without checking anything previously.

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you checked that your IP have not changed since you created the socket? I mean, are you binding to a static IP?

Comment: Its a Debian Linux server with static IP.

Comment: This is not normal. Show your code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Havenard/e930be035a3bee75c018

Comment: A few (stylistic) hints on the sourcecode: 1) the main() function is way too large to be readable 2) The signalhandler is defined inside main(). C does not have nested functions. 3) you test your file descriptors against zero ( `'if (skt_accept == 0)... )` try to use -1 as invalid filedescriptor (and set them to -1 when invalid) 4) in your gobackground() function you do a printf after closing filedesctiptors 0,1,2. 5) you really should ignore some of the -1 returns from select(), such AS EAGAIN. 6) The linked lists are messy and overly complicated, IMHO. 7)  `' '` is more readable than 0x20

Comment: I know, this source is almost 10 years old. I was not exactly a good programmer at that time.

Comment: send() to a closed socket will trigger a SIGPIPE but it should kill your program straight away....

Comment: send() SIGPIPE continuation : socket closure can come from remote TCP CLOSE, and since you are not protected against SIGPIPE... Is your program restarted automatically ?

Comment: @nullix I'm not sure what you mean by remote TCP close. Its a listening socket, tecnically its not connected to any peer. I never send() or recv() from it. When a connection is accepted, its accepted as a new socket.

Comment: FYI, programs like `inetd` keep listening  ports open for months, and they don't get closed. Have you tried running your program with a memory debugging tool like valgrind, to see if there's some wayward pointers messing things up?

Comment: @Havenard Right i am not taklink about send on listening socket but send on accepted socket. One of your 30 clients might disconnect abruptly from your irc/like server while you are still talking to it. when it happens if your ever try to send() something to client socket whole program will quit with SIGPIPE.

Comment: @Barmar I've seen `inetd` source code, and it does a health check every 10 seconds or so, and has a full restart procedure (close all  FDs and start a new process) in case its attempt to connect to itself fails for any reason. And it does that quite uglily I should say, I was amazed with how many hacks I saw in such essential Linux service. But anyway, I could only conclude that health checks are indeed necessary, sinse not even `inetd` takes its listening port for granted.

Comment: @Havenard I've never heard of sockets getting closed spontaneously. But some OSes have admin tools that can forcibly close sockets, that may be what it's protecting against.

Comment: What *symptom* do you encounter? Does 'netstat' cease showing the port as LISTENING for example?

Comment: Yes. `netstat` no longer accuses the port as open.

Answer (score 6):

I would start by cleaning it up:

- cut it up into smaller, readable, verifyable , testable functions
- the linked lists usage look messy; it could be simplified a lot, maybe by introducing some generic functions.
- replace all the silly '\x20' character constants by the more readable ' ' equivalents
- avoid manifest magic constants like here `if (n_case > 0) memcpy(nick, node->nick, (n_case > 32 ? 32 : n_case));` ; sizeof is your friend.
- don't use zero as a sentinel value for an unused file descriptor; use -1 instead.
- use unsigned types for sizes and indexes; negative indexes will corrupt memory, fold-over unsigned types will fail fast. (failfast is your friend)

That's only a few hours of editing.

My guess is that, after cleanup/refactoring your "bug" will come to the surface magically.

*Footnote: No,I won't do your work for you. Not for 100 points, not for 1000. Please clean up your own mess.*

Comment: This old code is just an exemple of a program I know that will eventually give the problem. I wrote other similar programs that have the same problem, one of which runs on a Windows Server. I have no doubt it is not the program that is causing the issue, because as you can see, it should exit both if `select()` returns <0 and if `skt_bind` is set to zero by some exception. Those are the only ways it will close the socket `skt_bind` and and in both of them it will terminate the program, which is not happening, meaning `skt_bind` still exists as a valid socket, despite the port is closed.

Comment: My doubt really is what could possibly close an open port without my program concern and how should I handle it properly. I already tried to simulate a couple network accidents like IP change or network cable disconnection, but nothing makes the port close, nor will it stop working because of that. It closes after long time open, and because of this long time factor its pretty hard to me to monitor and test how to proceed.

Comment: It's not closed without your program's concern: it's certain that the listening fd is closed by your program somewhere in a bug of your making. Whack in a printf of the fd's value after it's created (or find it out with lsof), then in gdb put a break on dup2, close, and fclose to find the place in your code where you stop listening.

Comment: It has been my experience (30 years of it) that **every** time a programmer says _"I have no doubt it is not the program that is causing the issue"_ they eventually prove themselves wrong.  Then again, could you have an intermittent network interruption that is enough for Windows to declare the interface non-functional, possibly triggering the close, and then declare it functional again?  If not that, then the problem really is most likely in your code.  Somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is mostly a code review of places where you call `close()`.

Line 330: You close the socket but don't continue right away like in other places in your code. This could lead to weird behavior.

Line 928: In most places, you set the client or server socket to `0` after a call to `close()`. You don't after this call.

Line 1193: Same comment as line 928.

Line 1195: Same comment as line 928.

Line 1218: Same comment as line 928.

Line 1234: Same comment as line 928.

Line 1236: Same comment as line 928.

When I compiled the code with full warnings, I saw a number of places where the compiler noted functions declared to return a value, but no value is being returned.

```
x.c:582: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
x.c:591: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
x.c:598: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
x.c:609: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
x.c:620: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
x.c:728: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
x.c:779: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
```

There are many other problems, as noted in other posts.

As far as debugging this issue, If I suspected the binding socket was being closed early, I would intercept the `close()` call with my own version that asserts that the descriptor being closed should not match the binding socket.

However, as wildplasser noted, `select()` would return an error about the invalid descriptor if it was closed.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is that you are using 0 as invalid file descriptor. 0 is perfectly valid and is usually stdin. Then the listener is set to 0 in the signal handler. Then you use 0 as no fd, and at some point you do close(0) on some socket, there are branches that do close(fd) without checkoing it for  0 and that effectively closes the listener. 
The other possible option to stop the listener from working is to overflow the backlog.

And one more problem - using unsigned int for fds.
system calls return -1 on error ... and that error would not be detected
with if assigned to unsigned int
struct identd_node -> unsigned int handle;
struct thread_node ->  unsigned int skt_clnt, skt_serv;

Comment: That was my bullet#6. Using 0 as a sentinel value for fds is indeed very wrong.

Comment: Doesnt really matter. Its only checked against 0 if its set to that value by a signal. Theres no other way it will change its value at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code needs to have 2 consecutive errors to cause a failure.

If you get an error from select, why not print out why straight away?

On line 281, printf errno/perror to find out what the problem is?

Comment: If it ever reached that point, the program would terminate. It is not terminating, it just go on as if everything was fine.

Comment: Oh yeah and this idea of checking twice was taken from Linux inetd source code. It checks twice too!

Answer (score 0):

Though the system should not behave as described, it sometimes does that. For server systems usually you need to perform a healthcheck call, either externally (from script), or from a special thread in your code.

So, if you detect that you can't connect to server in few consecutive attempts (few is needed due to possible overload condition), you can consider socket broken and recreate it or restart the server.

Comment: Sometimes does that ***when?*** I've never seen this behaviour in several decades of networkin programming.